# Azure VM's temporary storage drive and number of data disks that can be added

Tags: azure

I have a standard A5 VM which is supposed to have a 4 data disk capacity. The portal allowed me to attach 4 empty disks to the VM, but in Windows Server Manager I was only able to initialize the last three that I added. When right clicking the first one the only option was to bring it online.

Does a VM's temp storage (D:) count towards the number of data disks that can be added to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the temporary drive has nothing to do with attached disks. You can attach two disks per core, in addition to your temp drive (regardless of VM sku, and independent of regular vs premium storage disks, which are available with DS and GS series).

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the first disk I attach is automatically offline, and it turns out all I needed to do was put it online which then allows me to initialize it. Do you know if the temp drive is just a partition on the OS disk?

Comment: The Azure docs say: "When you create an Azure virtual machine, it has a disk for the operating system mapped to drive C and a temporary disk mapped to drive D.", so I guess that answers the question in my comment.